# SonarQube Quality Profiles are not being used during the sonarqube scan

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**SonarQube Quality Profiles are not being used  during the sonarqube scan:**

We have sonar tasks installed and enabled for build definition what we are seeing is that the quality profiles are being stopped for one build run and it is again started using the quality profiles for the next run automatically. We are consistently seeing the same behavior for the alternate build runs.

Image where we can see the profiles are stopped and started:

[image]

Comment: Do any of your non-issue-related metrics swing wildly along with these profile changes?

Comment: I'm not sure if i got your right, if you are asking about change in issues reported, then yes there's a huge difference as most of the file types get excluded from analysis resulting in very few issues reported. If that's not the information you were looking for, can you please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of a bad configuration somewhere. You indicate your comments that along with the toggling of profiles, you also see large swings in issue counts

> as most of the file types get excluded from analysis resulting in very few issues reported.

So let's break this down:

The profile events you're seeing simply record/reflect the changes in profile use from one analysis to another. If I have a project with Java and JavaScript, the first analysis will use the default profiles for that language. Then, let's say I use the *deprecated* property `sonar.language` to restrict analysis to just Java files and analyze again. Since JavaScript is no longer found in my project, the default JavaScript profile will not be used, and a profile event will be recorded.

That seems to be what you're seeing in your activity log.

So now to the detective work: why is this happening? First, this swings back and forth. That indicates configurations set not at the project level (in SonarQube itself) but properties that are only *sometimes* passed during the analysis, or some other analysis-side circumstance. There are a few possible causes which you'll need to investigate independently:

- `sonar.language` - if this *deprecated* property is used during analysis, it will limit the by-default multi-language analysis to a single language. It could be in your properties files or passed on the analysis command line `-Dsonar.language=foo`
- exclusions - exclusions are difficult to set properly from the analysis side, but this can happen
- improper/incomplete checkout - is it possible that only part of your project is checked out?

In investigating this, you should be aware that analysis-side properties can be set at two levels; at the individual project/analysis or in the global scanner configuration.

I'm guessing that your CI system has multiple slaves and languages are dropped - or not - from your project depending on which slave the job lands on that night.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem and I believe I have tracked down the root of the issue for us. Capturing the source code and properties used during the build, I was unable to find any discrepancies in sonar properties or source code collected, as suggested in the previous answer.

Our solution we were trying to analyze with SonarQube has a few C# projects that are part of an external core solution, which is shared between several components. Compiling any one of these other components requires that core be compiled first. I believe the issue lies in that when compiling my component to be analyzed, MsBuild would sometimes rebuild some of the projects included in core. Depending on if they were rebuilt or not, the number of projects and files (and hence issues) would swing wildly in one direction or the other.

**By enforcing MsBuild to clean my component solution before compiling**,

```
MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Clean,Build
```

**I ensure a consistent set of projects are built and analyzed by sonarqube.** I am 30 builds in with this new approach and I have no more flopping back and forth between using and not using a quality profile.